# Convert textbox's text (containing different characters of different font & color ) into image or picturebox

Tags: vb.net, image, picturebox, bitmapimage

I am doing project in **vb.net**
I am using a Rich text box on which i can set **different font** (name,size,bold,italic,underline),color to different selected text.
I am **able to do this in Rich textbox** but i want to create **bitmap** (or assign to picturebox) of this of different text with different font style & color but i am getting not much font as like textbox in image..
Is there any method to convert Rich textbox text directly to image which contain different font style & color for different text.

output should like following image....

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's a TextBox? AFAIK, text boxes do not allow differently formatted text - all the text entered is in the same font face, style and size.

Comment: Sorry sorry its not textbox its **Rich Textbox**

Comment: EM_FORMATRANGE is required to let RTB render its content.  Typically used for printing, just change the hdc in this code to Graphics.GetHdc() from Graphics.FromImage(): http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812425

Answer (score 0):

Kindly take a look at [this article](http://stpetrus27.wordpress.com/2011/08/24/c-rtf-to-image/).

http://stpetrus27.wordpress.com/2011/08/24/c-rtf-to-image/

It should provide you with what you need.